Какую версию Kafka client выбрать в 2024
В связи с тем, что pykafka получала последние обновления в 2018г., и kafka-python в 2020, подскажите, какой пакет для работы с Kafka используете.

Сам разработчик Кафки Confluent предлагает свой клиент confluent-kafka-python, он недавно обновлялся.

Confluent, a leading developer and maintainer of Apache Kafka®, offers confluent-kafka-python on GitHub. This Python client provides a high-level producer, consumer, and AdminClient that are compatible with Kafka brokers (version 0.8 or later), Confluent Cloud, and Confluent Platform.

